# How to update state only for visual effect in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After click on delete button i want to make the selectedPost to null so that user gets a prompt to select post again. I am updating the state onDeleteClick(). But everytime i am updating, componentDidMount is getting called and update the data of selectedPost.

Is there any other way to make the state to null so that user get the specific prompt?

```
class FullPost extends Component {
state = {
    selectedPost: null,
    postVisible: false
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.id) {
        if (!this.state.selectedPost || (this.state.selectedPost && this.state.selectedPost.id !== this.props.id)) {
            axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + this.props.id)
                .then(response => {
                    this.setState({ selectedPost: response.data })
                }
                );
        }
    }
}

onDeleteClick = () => {
    this.props.deletePost(this.state.selectedPost.id);

    this.setState({ selectedPost: null });

    console.log(this.state.selectedPost);
}

render() {
    let post = <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Please select a Post!</p>;
    if (this.state.selectedPost) {
        post = (
            <div className="FullPost">
                <h1>{this.state.selectedPost.title}</h1>
                <p>Content</p>
                <div className="Edit">
                    <button className="Delete"
                        onClick={this.onDeleteClick}>
                        Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
    return post;
}
```

}

Comment: Change `componentDidUpdate` to `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Won't work. Cause i  have to use update life cycle hooks.And it's triggered by parent component